# why did I lose -100 reputation for "User removed"?

Tags: support

I saw this new "User removed" in my list of reputation history.  Unlike all other things, you can't click it at all.  It doesn't seem to be related to any post but is just a -100 reputation loss.

While most things say upvote or downvote in the summary, this one instead says "removed".

So what is this?  I was just curious on this one as I had never seen something like that on SO before that was not self-explanatory.

(Filed under support as it almost looks like a bug or at least the fact I can't click it should be a bug as I should be able to read up on why this thing was and I can't).

later,
Dean

Comment: A user that voted up ten of your answers, twenty of your questions or some combination of questions and answers was removed (voluntarily or forcibly) and that nullified the votes.